# Wrong $PWD variable in Mac directory

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I have a Rails repository that, for some reason, has the wrong entry for `ENV["PWD"]` or `$PWD`. My other folders seem to be fine, but this one is wrong.

I believe it may have been caused by moving the repository after it was first created.

Where would this variable be stored, and how can I permanently fix it?

--- Context ---

The error is being thrown by a Ruby script that is trying to call `File.stat(ENV['PWD'])`.
When I run `$PWD`, it returns `zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/me/forecasts`.

This directory does indeed not exist; the correct directory is `/Users/me/Documents/forecasts`.

If PWD isn't stored anywhere, how is it loading the wrong data?

Comment: It's not stored. Under some circumstances, it's automatically set to the current working directory; in others, it's not. How are you using it, what's it coming out as, and why do you expect it to be something different?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I added more context.

Comment: Running `$PWD` makes no sense and should result in an error message since the PWD is a directory, not an executable program. You also say "The error is being thrown by a Ruby script" but don't tell us what the error is. Beyond that, I'll reiterate Gordon's point that PWD is set by the shell. Depending on your shell it may be a logical path (i.e., includes symlinks) or may be a physical path (i.e., symlinks resolved to their target). It would probably help to ignore your Ruby code for the moment and concentrate on the value of PWD as shown by your shell; i.e., at a shell prompt `echo $PWD`.

Comment: Try `echo $PWD`.